# How to compare the results of control vs variation?

Tags: sql, analysis

I'm trying to compare the control and variation(s) across tests.

```
test_name                        country    variant     value       delta
20230403_PO_KnC_DFSurchar         FP-HK     Control     33.57150594 null
20230403_PO_KnC_DFSurchar         FP-HK    Variation1   33.36300636 -0.20849957794
2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW     Control     47.81684982 null
2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW    Variation1   37.30776942 -10.50908039
2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW    Variation2   50.11678832 12.8090188976
```

[image]

```
SELECT test_name, country, variant, value, 
value- lag(value) OVER (partition by test_name order by variant) as delta
FROM base
ORDER BY 1,2
```

However, I get the delta not only between control and variation, but also the delta between the variations due to the lag function.
Is there any way that I can get delta only between control and variation across the test?

My expected outcome would be

```
    test_name                        country    variant     value       delta
    20230403_PO_KnC_DFSurchar         FP-HK     Control     33.57150594 null
    20230403_PO_KnC_DFSurchar         FP-HK    Variation1   33.36300636 -0.20849957794
    2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW     Control     47.81684982 null
    2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW    Variation1   37.30776942 -10.50908039
    2023601_TW_R_Eleasticity_Kin      FP_TW    Variation2   50.11678832 2.2999385
```

*Look at the last row, the delta from between control and variation2 not variation1- variation2.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: You have many options, use conditional max() over partition or lag with ignore nulls or make self join or recursive query. Some [working examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/vd3rlWF_). Many depends on environment you are using (which system: SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL etc) which version. And important question: can you have several Control rows per (test_name, country)?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the delta only between the control and variation values across the test, you can modify the query by adding a filter condition to exclude the delta calculation between variations. Here's an example of how you can modify the query to achieve this:

```
SELECT test_name, country, variant, value,
       CASE WHEN variant = 'control' THEN value - lag(value) OVER (PARTITION BY test_name ORDER BY variant) END AS delta
FROM base
WHERE variant IN ('control', 'variation')
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I also thought about Where function, however with this function, WHERE variant IN ('control', 'variation1'), I won't get the deltas of control and variation2.  If I add 'variation2' in the where function for example, then it will show the same problem, calculating the delta between variation1 and variation2 instead of the difference between control and variation2. :/

Comment: @Jenny please consider updating your question with the input and expected output.I don't see the test_name in what you provided

Comment: @SiddharthGhatge using the ORDER BY clause with column positions is generally not recommended. The main reason is that it makes the query less readable and harder to maintain, especially when it becomes more complex or changes the column order.